# Uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: objective-c

i am using tutorialspoint.com for compiling objective c code

```
@interface Foo{
@public
NSInteger x;
}
-(int) apple;
-(void)setAge:(NSInteger)number;
@end

@implementation Foo
-(int)apple{return 5;}

-(void)setAge:(NSInteger)number{
self->x=number+1;
NSLog(@"%d",self->x);
}
@end


int main (int argc, const char * argv[]){
NSAutoreleasePool *myPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
Foo *p = [[Foo alloc] init];NSInteger nine = 9;
[p setAge:nine];
[myPool drain];
return 0;
}
```

**and i get this compilation error when i try to compile it:**

```
main.m:41:3: warning: (Messages without a matching method signature   
main.m:41:3: warning: will be assumed to return 'id' and accept       
main.m:41:3: warning: '...' as arguments.)
```

Comment: In which line? Obviously your code snippet does not have 41 lines. BTW: The code is terrible.

Comment: warning is in this line Foo *p = [[Foo alloc] init];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class `Foo` has no base class (i. e. `NSObject`). Therefore `+alloc` and `-init` are not known for this class.

```
@interface Foo : NSObject {
…
```